# Replacing text from regex match with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

This is driving me crazy, what is the reason this doesn't work?

```
var name = data.match(/first-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/g).replace('first-', '');
```

I want to replace `first-joe` with `joe`.

I also tried

```
var name = data.match(/first-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/g);
var name = name.replace('first-', '');
```

and that doesn't work.

However the when alerting name I get `first-joe`

What is the reason for this, and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` with `/g` returns an array of matches (excluding parenthesized substrings), so you would have to `replace` them individually. If you know there is exactly one match, use `data.match(/first-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/)[1]` which extracts the parenthesized substring.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
var name = data.replace(/first-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/g, '$1');
```

Comment: data is the contents of a GET request, when I do this it just alerts the source

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're calling match first. Why not simply do either of these?

```
var name1 = data.replace('first-', '');
var name2 = data.replace(/^first-/, ''); //In case somebodys got a name containing first-.
```

Is it because your data variable contains something more than the string 'first-joe'?